# Acumatica Using $filter programmatically gives HTTP 400 Bad request

Tags: php, acumatica

I am using this url in my php code

```
https://awesomedomain.app/entity/Default/18.200.001/SalesOrder?$filter=Status eq 'Completed'
```

Like this:

```
$acumaticaOrder = $this->Acumatica_API("/entity/Default/18.200.001/SalesOrder?$" . 'filter' . "=Status eq 'Completed'", 'GET');
```

But it gives **"Bad request"** error

[image]

Whereas, i am using same link in **Postman**, but it gives me those orders marked as Completed.

[image]

I even checked the URL i am making and copy pasted the same URL in **Postman**, in **Postman** it works. But programmatically it gives HTTP 400 Bad request.

Comment: why are you concatenating 'filter'?

Comment: I think i didnot understand you. I am concatenating 'filter' because i want to use it. And i am concatenating it separately because in API the 'filter' should be used with dollar sign like this $filter=Status eq 'Completed' and with 'Completed' single quotation would work. So i have to wrap whole string around double quotations. And double quotations causes $filter to be denoted as a PHP variable. That's why i am concatenating in this manner.

Comment: @PatrickChen i even tried like this but it still says bad request

$acumaticaOrder = $this->Acumatica_API('/entity/Default/18.200.001/SalesOrder?$filter=Status eq ' . "'Completed'", 'GET');

Comment: other query params such as $expand, seems to work without any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string should be structured like this:

> $url = 'http://localhost/Acumatica20R2DB/entity/Default/20.200.001/SalesOrder?$filter=Status%20eq%20%27Completed%27';

The single quote will have PHP ignore your $ and you'll need to use the html encoding for spaces and 's in your filter.